# Populate a datagridview with a list in the correct order

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datagridview

Basically I have different lists: Employee,Cooker, and Teacher.

When I want to populate my datagridview with one of them, it doesn't show me the values of the object in a correct order. What do I mean with the correct order? If my class has id, name and salary attributes or properties, I want to show them in the same order, not like salary, name and id. I applied inheritance so I don't know if that can cause some issues.

I only tried to populate my datagridview with this.

```
dgvEmployess.DataSource = listOfCookers;
```

Here are my classes

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Employee
{
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }
}

public class Cooker : Employee
{
    public int ExtraHours { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns are created automatically by default if you didn't create it manually.

```
dgvEmployess.AutoGenerateColumns = false; // Disable automated columns creation 
dgvEmployess.DataSource = listOfCookers;
```

Create columns manually with needed order and set `DataPropertyName` to property name like salary

[image: Create columns manually]

Comment: Thank you sir.Now I can finish my project

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches could be creating a custom attribute that defines the order of the class property in the display and a function that reads the custom attributes values and sorts the columns:

```
public class ColumnOrder : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

In the class, set the order (In this example the order will be Id, Age, Salary, Name):

```
public class Person
{
    [ColumnOrder(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ColumnOrder(Order = 25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ColumnOrder(Order = 3)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    [ColumnOrder(Order = 10)]
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Use this extension to order the columns by it's `ColumnOrder` attribute value. It iterates the properties of the type, reads the value of the `ColumOrder` and changes the `DisplayIndex` of the column:

```
public static class ColumnExtensions
{
    public static void OrderByProperties(this DataGridViewColumnCollection columns,  Type t)
    {
        var columnList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
        {
            var att = prop.GetCustomAttributes<ColumnOrder>( true).First();
            if(att!=null)
            {
                columnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(prop.Name,att.Order));
            }
        }

        foreach (var order in columnList.OrderBy(a => a.Value).Select((value, i) => new {i, value }))
        {
            columns[order.value.Key].DisplayIndex = order.i;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, after binding the datasource, call to OrderByProperties with the correct type:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.OrderByProperties(typeof(Employee));
```